Android 14 AVD crashes on when simulating calls or SMS messages

These two features work fine with Android 10 image, but with Android 14 image, one CPU core goes to 100% and after about 10 seconds it crashes.
Any workaround for this?
Environment:

Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 2
Fedora 40, KDE

